# Retrieving a Subset of Fields from MongoDB in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, subset

I'm trying to get a subset of fields from MongoDB with a query made in Ruby but it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't return any results

This is the ruby code:

```
coll.find("title" => 'Halo', :fields => ["title", "isrc"]) #this doesn't work
```

If I remove the fields hash, it works, returning the results with all the fields

```
coll.find("title" => 'Halo') #this works
```

Looking at the mongodb console the first query ends-up on the mongodb server like this:

```
{ title: "Halo", fields: [ "title", "isrc" ] }
```

If I try to make the query from the mongo client console, it works, I get the results and the subset. I make the query like this:

```
db.tracks.find({title: 'Halo'}, {title:1,isrc:1})
```

What could be the problem? I've been looking for a solution for this for a couple of hours now.

Comment: Can you try: `coll.find({"title" => 'Halo'}, :fields => ["title", "isrc"])`

Comment: Please note that current ruby driver changed the name of the option key from `:fields` to `:projection`. http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The query should look like

```
collection.find(selector = {}, opts = {})
```

[Query the database](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method)

In your case it is

```
coll.find({"title" => 'Halo'}, {:fields => ["title", "isrc"]})
```

But still remains a problem, the ruby-driver ignores the condition of "fields", and returns **all the fields**! :\

Comment: This worked for me, the ruby-driver didn't ignore the "fields" option. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken, the ruby-driver don't ignore the :fields option. This issue of ODM, I use Mongoid, but in MongoMapper it is also present. You can read about this problem [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mongomapper/browse_thread/thread/b5c263d835ac0d2).

Comment: It may be useful to note that according to the MongoDB documentation you always get the _id unless you specifically exclude it with field negation. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields

Comment: Latest ruby driver (as linked) changed `fields` option name to `projection`. So of course `fields` key is ignored.

Comment: @Vladimir in Mongoid use `Model.only(:title, :isrc).where(...)` and it will correctly construct your object, but throw if you try to access another field

Answer (score 13):

As of Sep, 2015, these other answers are outdated.  You need to use the projection method: `#projection(hash)`

```
coll.find({"title" => 'Halo'}).projection({title: 1, isrc: 1})
```

Comment: Or `coll.find({"title" => "Halo"},{projection: {title: 1, isrc: 1}})`.

Answer (score 10):

This query will return only the title and isrc for a doc that has the title "Halo":

```
coll.find({"title" => 'Halo'},{:fields => {"_id" => 0, "title" => 1, "isrc" => 1}})
```

Note the use of a Hash for the fields where the keys are the field names and the values are either 1 or 0, depending on whether you want to include or exclude the given field.

Comment: Thanks - I've been trying to find how to negate fields with the Ruby driver (a projection specifying to not return the _id field). That doesn't seem to be well-documented for the Ruby driver.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below query

```
coll.find({"title" => 'Halo'}).projection({title: 1, isrc: 1, _id: 0})
```

if you don't want _id, to be retrieved in case.